# Using 3D designs in java

Tags: java, 3d

I am currently trying to practice 3D program designs in java, but unfortunately when I try to import the following packages, it gives says that the package does not exist.

```
import com.sun.j3d.utils.geometry.ColorCube;

import javax.media.j3d.BranchGroup;

import com.sun.j3d.utils.universe.SimpleUniverse;
```

Could anyone help me to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 3D API is not part of the standard API. You'll need to download and install it before using classes from it in your code.

See: http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/java3d/index.jsp